# Connect to Team Server on launch of VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I deal with multiple Team Foundation Servers and collections. Is there a command line I can send to VS so I don't have to manually switch between the TFS servers every time I launch VS?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is use the start page from Visual Studio. It lists my **recent projects** and you can even pin them so they do not scroll out of view when you do not use them for a while.

Activating a project from the start page will **automatically** connect your Visual Studio environment to the correct TFS collection, because the solution you open is *bound* to one of them.

Works like a charm!

[image]